# How to create a pointer to a buffer in a typedef struct in C?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I getting an incompatible-pointer-types error when trying to Initialize a typedef struct with a pointer to a char buffer.
The struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct otCryptoKey
{
    const uint8_t *mKey;       ///< Pointer to the buffer containing key. NULL indicates to use `mKeyRef`.
    uint16_t       mKeyLength; ///< The key length in bytes (applicable when `mKey` is not NULL).
    uint32_t       mKeyRef;    ///< The PSA key ref (requires `mKey` to be NULL).
} otCryptoKey;
```

This is what i have tried, and i also tried to initialize with all the parameters in the struct.

```
    uint8_t mKey[16] = "1234567891012131";
    uint8_t *mKeyPointer = mKey;

    otCryptoKey *aKey = {mKeyPointer};
```

Can anyone figure out why i get this error?

Comment: Try `otCryptoKey aKey = {mKeyPointer};`  (no `*`).  Should `aKey` be a _pointer_ or an instance of `otCryptoKey`?

Comment: @Jenath You are trying to assign one pointer with a pointer of another type . This statement otCryptoKey *aKey = {mKeyPointer}; does not make sense.

Comment: Another thing is that mKey is 16, means 15 + 1 for the NULL char, you should assign 15 chars to that variable, not 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a pointer to a `otCryptoKey` and attempting to initialize it with a pointer to `uint8_t`.  Those types are not compatible.

What you want is to create an `otCryptoKey` object and initialize the `mKey` member with that pointer.

```
otCryptoKey aKey = {mKey, sizeof mKey, 0};
```

Answer (score 0):

That syntax initializes a struct, not a pointer to a struct.

You should instead do: `otCryptoKey aKey = {mKeyPointer};`

Or better yet, use named fields and lose the intermediate variable: `otCryptoKey aKey = { .mKey = mKey };`